# How do I remove the rainbow colours from the gutter in PhpStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I don't even know what this setting is called.

When in an HTML document I get some rainbow colours in the gutter, I guess to tell me the indentation/nesting level of the current part of the doc I am working on.

However I don't want it, I find this distracting.

Comment: I believe they refer to it as the Marker Bar - not sure if you can disable it in PhpStorm?

Comment: This is really a StackOverflow question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have finally found it.

It is in the settings under `Editor` > `Appearance` > `Enable HTML/XML tag tree highlighting`

Comment: This also removes the shitty green injected lanuage highlighting. It is the only way to remove those two things. Thanks alot